# Not able to apply guard expression in query list comprehension

Tags: erlang, lfe

I am trying a query list comprehension:

```
> (set xs '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
> (lc ((<- x xs) (when (> x 5))) x)
```

But I am getting the error `exception error: undefined function when/1`.

Is it possible to apply guard statements to `lc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [LFE User Guide](https://github.com/rvirding/lfe/blob/develop/doc/user_guide.txt), within a list comprehension qualifier, the guard must precede the list expression:

> (<- pat {{guard}} list-expr)

This means your example should be written as follows:

```
lfe> (set xs '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
lfe> (lc ((<- x (when (> x 5)) xs)) x)
(6 7 8)
```

You could alternatively treat the greater-than expression as a normal boolean expression qualifier:

```
lfe> (lc ((<- x xs) (> x 5)) x)
(6 7 8)
```